# Modelling of building interior and exterior for scene

Tags: modeling, animation

I want to model the interior of a house, inside the house. By this I mean that I have a scene where the outside of the house is modelled but the inside of the house also needs to be modelled. What is the practical method to do this?

Comment: If in all one file, one important feature to use is the organization of Collections and scenes and views, so that you can hide interior furnishings while rendering exteriors and visa versa.  This will reduce render times and memory requirements that can otherwise overwhelm your machine.  I even hide all bedroom furnishings when rendering say, the kitchen or entry foyer.  Also with differing scenes, you can adjust animation of a door opening only where needed for a camera walk-through, or in having lighting changes (animate time of day or control light groups).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.